# Import from Excel into Multi Indexed dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, multi-index

I'm trying to import from Excel into a dataframe and maintain a multi indexed format.

This import is fine:

```
def import_cp(cp_sheet_name):
    xl = pd.ExcelFile('FileNameA.xlsx')
    df_first = xl.parse(cp_sheet_name)
    df_second = xl.parse(cp_sheet_name)
    # there's many more
    return df_first, df_second

df_first = import_cp("Sheet 1")
```

The Excel is formatted like this:

```
|        |       Alpha       |       Bravo      |    Charlie     |
|Position|  Area   |  Gain   |   Area  |  Gain  |  Area  |  Gain |
|    1   |   0.5   |   1.1   |    0.5  |  1.1   |   1.7  |  1.6  |
|    2   |   0.6   |   1.0   |    0.6  |  1.0   |   1.5  |  1.4  |
```

Where the Alpha Bravo cells are merged.

When I import I get:

```
(  |Unnamed: 0 Alpha| Unnamed: 2 Bravo| Unnamed: 4 Charlie|
0  |Position    Area|   Gain    Area  |  Gain    Area     |
1  |    1     0.5   |   1.17    0.5   |    1.13     0.5   |
2  |    2     0.5   |   1.17    0.5   |    1.13     0.5   |
```

I tried using `header=0` however that did not have change much and a `fillna` is not ideal as I don't want `Alpha Alpha Bravo Bravo Charlie Charlie`

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need add parameter `header=[0,1]` to [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) for reading columns to `MultiIndex`,  `index_col=0` for reading first column to `index` and `sheetname='sheet1'` for reading `sheet` with name `sheet1`. Then you can reset columns names by [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) (new in `pandas` `0.18.0`)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', header=[0,1], index_col=0, sheetname='sheet1')
print df
         Alpha      Bravo      Charlie     
Position  Area Gain  Area Gain    Area Gain
1          0.5  1.1   0.5  1.1     1.7  1.6
2          0.6  1.0   0.6  1.0     1.5  1.4

df = df.rename_axis((None,None), axis=1)
print df
  Alpha      Bravo      Charlie     
   Area Gain  Area Gain    Area Gain
1   0.5  1.1   0.5  1.1     1.7  1.6
2   0.6  1.0   0.6  1.0     1.5  1.4

print df.index
Int64Index([1, 2], dtype='int64')

print df.columns
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'Alpha', u'Bravo', u'Charlie'],
                   [u'Area', u'Gain']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

Comment: Hi Jezrael, thank you for the answer! I'm getting an error: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list. Is this a problem with the header setting?

Comment: I dont know, I think parameters `0` and `1` in `header=[0,1]` means read first and second row in excel file to columns. Btw, what is your version of pandas? `print pd.show_versions()` ?

Comment: I'm running 0.16.2 at the moment... but the update button isn't showing any updates? Should I try and download 0.18?

Comment: What is your [`OS`](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/operating-system-OS)? `Windows`, `Linux`?

Comment: And use `Anaconda` ? I think you can check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html)

Comment: Pycharm. However I am downloading the newest version now and will check your solution again. I'll keep you updated!

Comment: Finally managed to update it. Never had so many issues before! Thank you yes your solution has worked! Just needed to update is all.